# I messed up with with replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016

Currently we are building a new prod environment that will have replication just like the old current prod environment.

The dev server gets refreshed daily however we had to pause the refresh due to replication set up for testing before it goes out to the new prod. So I wanted to keep refreshing dev while replication is there, I restored a backup from current prod with keep replication command to the dev but it looks like that has overwritten the publication and the subscription with prod name in dev. I tried to drop it but I am getting an error saying that the current prod is not configured as subscriber for the dev.

I am completely messed! So my question is: will running the sp drop replication ignoring distribution=1, affect the subscription in the current prod? We don’t want that to happen. If so I am messed up, please can anyone help?